# Why I am getting compile time error as 'else' without 'if'. Can anyone explain me with detail

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

**Why I am getting compile time error as 'else' without 'if'. Can anyone explain me with detail**

```
class Test
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            if(false)
                if(true)
                    if(false)
                    else
                        System.out.println("1");
                else
                    System.out.println("2");
            else
                System.out.println("3");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just use Braces and they go away.

Comment: what is `if(false)else`  supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The innermost `if(false)` is missing a statement. Unless you want to use braces, you'll have to add a no-op statement after the `if`:

```
if(false);
else
    System.out.println("1");
```

Or you can invert your whole chain of `if`s:

```
if(true)
    System.out.println("3");
else if(false)
    System.out.println("2");
else if(true)
    System.out.println("1");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 concepts which are in use here:
1. If you do no use braces for a If statement, then compiler will only consider the very next line to the If statement as a complete If block.
2. You can not use an else statement alone. In simpler words, else statement can only be used if it has an If block.

For the innermost If statement, as you didn't used braces here, 'else' is the only statement to execute. And we can not use else statement alone.